# How to Opitmize this Update Statement

Tags: sql, performance, query-optimization

Let's say I have a table with 15 columns called MyTable and an `UPDATE` query like so:

```
UPDATE MyTable SET relevancy = 1, ruleName = 'myRule' 
WHERE colOne = 'some condition' AND colTwo = 5 ... 
  AND (RELEVANCY <> 1 OR RELEVANCY IS NULL)
```

The `...` represents any combination of the 15 columns in the `WHERE` condition (ie. it could be col14 and col10 and col1 or col11 and col14 only, etc)

What we're trying to do is we have a table with about 1M+ rows and we have these "filter rules" based on column values to set specific rows' relevancy to 1 so users can say something like: I want all these data from MyTable with col1 value of 'hello'. This UPDATE statement is also ran in a loop (~20 times).

What are ways to optimize this query? Assume that no optimizations have been done yet like indices (we don't have this yet as we're not sure which columns to index).

Comment: I don't see how you can do better than this if in fact you want to filter on any of these columns. Particularly when you don't know ahead of time which columns will be used to filter data.

Comment: @Jonathan, Unfortunately, yes, that is the case.

Comment: Are colOne and colTwo always specified in the WHERE clause?

Comment: @Catcall Not always but most of the time, probably around 80%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I can't see anything obviously wrong with the query itself, so the short answer is that you can't optimise this without first running it and looking at the query plan.  Because of the way that relational database work it can be very difficult to predict what the performance will be like simply by looking at the query as it depends on so many other hidden factors such as the data distribution, statistics, parameters supplied and other hidden internals.

That said, I'm struggling to understand the benefit of using this approach over just doing a normal select - the **only** benefit that I can see is that it would protect against poor indexing on the numbered columns for users doing a `SELECT` based on the `RELEVANCY` column (which presumably will always be properly indexed).

Also the schema you have specified would appear to limit `MyTable` to having only a single rule applied at any one time, and so you need to perform this `UPDATE` any time the filter is changed anyway.

What is it that you are trying to achieve?

---

When you can't determine in advance what the user is going to be querying on the only thing you can really do in terms of indexing is index all columns (individually) and hope for the best.

With many columns you may start to see a runtime performance penalty when updating or inserting into this table due to the large number of indexes that need updating, but the alternative most likely involves a table scan every time the user searches on a column that isn't indexed.

It also helps if you are prepared to alter the indexes on a case-per-case basis in the event that you start having problems with certain queries.

Answer (score 0):

One rule of thumb for speeding up SELECT queries is to index every column used in a JOIN expression or in a WHERE clause.

The trade-off is that UPDATE and DELETE queries change the row and some or all of the indexes. So adding indexes usually slows down the updating.

With 15 columns and a million rows, my guess is that the speed you gain by adding indexes will not be completely nullified by the speed you lose by the dbms having to update indexes. But I could be wrong.

But indexes are cheap. Update your statistics. Measure performance before adding indexes. Add the indexes. Measure performance again. Decide whether to keep the indexes or to drop them.

An index can have more than one column. If, for example, colOne and colTwo usually appear together in a WHERE clause, you might get better performance by creating one index on the pair of columns instead of creating two indexes, one on each column. Measure, index, measure again.

Most SQL dbms support some variation of `EXPLAIN queryname or SQL statement`. Find out what your dbms supports, and use that to measure performance.